# How to make Postgres character field sortable by number

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgressql table:

```
CREATE TABLE businesses
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      town character varying(200) NOT NULL,
      name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
      employees character varying(200) NOT NULL,
      offices character varying(200) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT businesses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```

I need to sort by number of employees. Unfortunately I realized that the table is of type character , which appears to be a string. Is there a way to modify the table without destroying it,  to turn the employees field into something sortable by number?

Comment: Do you want to change the table itself or you just want to sort the data in the query without changing the table?

Comment: Is there anything besides numbers (regexp: `^[0-9]+$`) in the column `employees` ?

Comment: I would probably want to change the table to it could be sorted by other fields if necessary but also by  the employees column. I will eventually need to export to excel and would like to be able to sort from there as well - Bill

Comment: The 'employees' field contains just string representations of integers

Comment: If the `employees` column truly only stores the count of employees it's better in the long run to correct the column type, rather than working around the clearly undesirable datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query to change the type of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ALTER employees TYPE numeric USING cast(employees as numeric);
```

You can find details here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: `integer` seems more appropriate than `numeric` for this case.

Comment: @faintsignal I prefer to use general `numeric` for cases where I do not have an exact external specification for data structure

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a simple `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ALTER COLUMN employees TYPE integer USING (CAST(employees AS integer))
```

but you may then need to adjust applications that use this table.

You can in the mean time

```
ORDER BY CAST(employees AS integer)
```

but it'll be slow and won't use any index.

Comment: Thank you very much Craig - Bill